# Resharper Custom Plugin Severity Options

Tags: c#, resharper, resharper-8.0

Hello I've been working on a custom ReSharper plugin which is almost done.  It highlights specified code elements with `[StaticSeverityHighlighting(Severity.WARNING, "NonLocalizedStrings")]`.  I would like to be able to set the severity just like other resharper warnings under Options > Code Inspection > Inspection Severity.  Where would I specify the name and group I'd like my inspection to show up as.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    [assembly: RegisterConfigurableSeverity(MakeMethodVirtualSuggestion.SeverityId,
  "CSHARP",
  HighlightingGroupIds.BestPractice,
  "Non Localized String",
  "All strings must be marked with either '// Not L10N' or localized to a resx file.",
  Severity.WARNING,
  false)]
```

Fixed with this assembly above the namespace

```
 [ConfigurableSeverityHighlighting("AccessToDisposedClosure", "CSHARP", OverlapResolve = OverlapResolveKind.WARNING, ToolTipFormatString = "Non Localized Strings")]
```

Using `ConfigurableSeverityHighlighting` on class fixes the problem.  Thank you again citizenmatt your git is very helpful